# Sync Framework: Oracle/SQLServer

Tags: sql-server, oracle, microsoft-sync-framework

I want to setup a sync service using Microsoft Sync Framework.
The main objective is to sync some tables between an Oracle Database and a SQL Server Database.

How can I do it? There are any `OracleSyncProvider`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem I used a Linked Server to the Oracle DB Server and after that I created a SQL SERVER JOB that runs the [Merge](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) command.

Answer (score 4):

if you go the Sync Framework way, there is a sample Oracle sync provider at: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Database-Sync-Oracle-and-037fb083

Answer (score 1):

There are several forms of third party software which will automate this process for you, however if you would like to do it manually I would suggest the Oracle `CREATE DATABASE LINK`.
This approach allows you to access information (tables,views, etc) from another database using the Heterogeneous Services.

Once you have established a connection between the two databases you can create a trigger for the Oracle tables which in-turn fire on updates/inserts/deletes so that the same action gets invoked on the Microsoft database.

See the following link for additional details on Oracle's `DATABASE LINK` : http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/statements_5005.htm

The same setup can be applied to the SQL server so that whenever an update/insert/delete is performed the correlating table in Oracle gets updated, "synced", as well. For the Microsoft approach to this see the following link, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx .