# bidirectional sync between SQL server and MySQL tables

Tags: mysql, sql-server, ssis, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

I want to setup a bidirectional sync between local tables in  SQL Server database and remote tables in MySQL database.

After many search, I find two ways:

1- Microsoft Sync Frameworke, but you must implement you own custom provider.

2- using SSIS and linked server as you can find  [here]:[Sync Framework: Oracle/SQLServer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8658617/sync-framework-oracle-sqlserver)

By using the second solution, I succeeded just in doing the synchronization in one direction.

Can someone help me doing the bidirectional sync ?

Answer (score 1):

In connection with my experience SSIS is the best way. I don't see any problems of synchronization back from mySql. You just should make 'buffer' database and organize process of merging data in this database from SQL server and MySql. After merging, values should be applied to both databases.

But, you can check such solutions like Oracle Golden Gate. This solution is pretty expensive, but in could provide real time synchronization for cross platform data.
Solution depends on question 'how often data should be synchronized'